# Not reevaluating expensive data in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, hashmap, synchronized

i have such a method

```
public Object doSomethingExpensive(String x);
```

now if i processed this method i can save the result in a HashMap for example, they key is the String x and the value is the result Object.

If the data is present in this map, i dont have to process it again.

But now i get two requests in, at nearly the same time.
And in this case i want to let the second request wait, till the first one is done and the second requests can also get the result of the first one after it is calculated, so i dont have to calculate it twice or parallel twice.

the point is, i can't use

```
public synchronized Object doSomethingExpensive(String x);
```

because Object is something other if String x is something other.
So i need some synchronized on that String x.

But synchronized(x) isn't possible because string literals in java....

Also if there wouldn't be a String but an Object as x, then maybe i get in the second requests a similar Object with equal content related to request 1, but they are some other objects each.

Yeah so my question is, how to solve this, how can i prevent calculating for a String x its result twice in parallel, how can i synchronize it and caching the results in a HashMap for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem, If it's to avoid repeated calculation, this great book([Java Concurrency in Practice](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601)) gives a example of a solution:

```
  private final Map<String, Future<Object>> cache
      = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Future<Object>>();

  public Object doSomethingExpensive(String x) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
      Future<Object> future = cache.get(x);
      if (future == null) {
        Callable<Object> callable = new Callable<Object>() {
          @Override
          public Object call() throws Exception {
            // doSomethingExpensive todo
            return new Object();
          }
        };
        FutureTask<Object> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(callable);
        future = cache.putIfAbsent(x, futureTask);
        if (future == null) {
          future = futureTask;
          futureTask.run();
        }
      }
      try {
        return future.get();
      } catch (CancellationException e) {
        cache.remove(x);
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT:
From comments, using `JAVA8#ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent`, really really convenient :

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Object doSthEx(String key) {
        return concurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(key, new Function<String, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(String s) {
                // todo 
                return new Object();
            }
        });
    }
```

Or use some library to get more comprehensive features as mentioned in comment:https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine.

Comment: This is natively supported in Java 8's `ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent` method. A caching library, like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population), adds support for bounding the size.

Comment: "Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple."
is written in the javadoc over computeIfAbsent. So if i use this to prevent caluclating for String X a result twice, i could also prevent calculating any other String x2 in this map?

Comment: @zysaaa why do you put the threading code (here as a FutureTask) into the doSomethingExpensive/computeIfAbsent?...... because of the problematic blocking also other operations in the map and so you make the synchronized block very short in time?

Comment: Future means that the key has been calculated, or is being calculated, just call ```Future #get``` to get the result.  Do you understand the first way?  @RobinKreuzer

Comment: yeah i understand both ways^^, but the question is here, why you ecapsulate the doSomethingExpensive() into a Future (and so into "an another thread"); what is your intention behind this? Is that intention that you can leave the synchronized intern in the concurrentMap as fast as you can?^^ But if i call the doSomethingMethod already from different threads, so how i can avoid creating a second thread in that method or in the computeIfAbsent-lambda-method?

Comment: @RobinKreuzer a Future ≠ "start an another thread" because I am using ```futureTask.run()``` not ```futureTask.start()``` or submit it to a ```thread pool```.  So everything here is in sync, you need to understand this.   Suppose thread A calls doSomethingExpensive(" A ") and finds that it isn't in the cache, that thread evaluates synchronically, and subsequent threads find that A ```Future``` already exists, All they need to do is call ```future#get``` to get the result. (```future#get``` blocks, regardless of whether the calculation is complete or not.)

Comment: The future is run within the atomic scope of the compute method, which unfortunately means it is adding boilerplate. Simple returning the loaded value will have the same effect, @zysaaa. At times an async cache can be useful, though.

Comment: I edited the answer again, as @BenManes  said, simple returning the loaded value will have the same effect!

Comment: (at)zysaa, but computeifAbsent blocks itself too, if the value isnt calculated yet. So that was the thing, what Ben Manes meant with boilerplate, i guess?. Anyway the computeIfAbsent-method can block also in other cases -> "Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple" <- And so it is a problem having in there a big computation. What would you do to prevent this @BenManes ,zysaa? Starting in it another thread could solve this? but would be another thread i don't want to have?!^^

Comment: @RobinKreuzer  Yes, if the value isnt calculated yet,  thread is blocked to wait result.  What are you trying to achieve?  If the result has not been calculated, does it return null directly?

Comment: @RobinKreuzer That documentation is because ConcurrentHashMap locks the hashbin which means a write to a different entry might be delayed. A typical cost like a database load is fine, but a very slow operation is a poor fit. In that case you would use a future but run it outside of the map operation by the inserting caller so that you get per entry locking and do not use additional threads. These are discussed in Caffeine’s [faq](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Faq).

Comment: @BenManes yeah exaclty this i mean (but you mention with this workaround something else too, manipulating the same map within that atomic-operation liveness-lock, i guess you mean this section also solving long-lasting-operations). Yeah i mean something which can last 5min i calculating. I solve it for me self not with Futures, but with a HolderObject. which i put into the Concurrent Map, and in outside area i do a synchronized on that HolderObject, after that getting or calculating the result (and store it then in the Holder object), i think this solution is equivalent to the Future solution?

Comment: Or is there some other nicer solution? And are they really eqivalent -> HolderObject and a synchronized on it (in outside of the map-operation) and the Future?. I want only beeing sure here. Anyway i wasnt concrete enough, and i think you @zysaaa good answered my question. Maybe- if you want - you can extend your answer with the problemtatic of long-running tasks 5min, that in that case you do what Ben Manes described in his FAQ. But if i could i would give both of you an accepted answer^^

Comment: @RobinKreuzer The future is a convenient holder object which contains an internal lock. It’s equivalent to a custom holder except nicer, built in, and has a well known intent. The two solutions (direct compute, future) differ by using either per entry locking or lock striping, which shares locks at a low collisions rate (the map’s initial capacity determines the number of locks). I don’t think there are any better solutions, just different styles for writing equivalent code.